# If a real, nonconstant polynomial has a local minimum at $a$, it is concave up somewhere close to $a$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a polynomial $f(x)$ with a local minimum at $(a,f(a))$, I want to conclude that $f$ is concave up at some point close to $a$.  I see that it is not necessarily true that $f$ is concave up at $a$, as the second derivative could be $0$ at $a$.  Any ideas on how this might be shown formally?  I feel as though it must be true but I cannot see how to prove it.

Comment: Does "concave up" mean the same as "convex"?

Comment: Concave up to me means the second derivative is greater than $0$.

Comment: I see, I have never run into this term.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), go down to strictly convex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is local minimum, then this means that on some neighbourhood $f$ is decreasing to the left of $a$ and increasing to the right of $a$, so that the derivative has changed the sign from negative to positive in the neighbourhood of $a$. By mean value theorem the derivative of derivative must be somewhere positive on this neighbourhood.

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of simple argument I was looking for.

Comment: I think you'll want to make an edit ... *somewhere* ... in your last sentence. :)

Comment: @Blue Thanks for pointing that out :) But you can't deny that polynomial has to have second derivative _somewhere_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see that $f$ has to be convex at the local minimum than using the derivative is as follows:

You can also argue using the epigraph (the set above the graph), which has to be of convex shape since in a neighborhood the function has to be non-increasing (graph goes up) to the left and non-decreasing (graph goes up) to the right [I find this way of describing a bit more intuitive] of its local minimum $(a,f(a))$ by the very definition.